# How to use $_SESSION with if() in PHP

Tags: php, session, if-statement

I've built a mobile detection with Mobile_Detect.php and it works great. Now if a User does not want to stay on the mobile site he can click on "Desktop-Version" and goes back to the main page via a 'mobile_off.php' which sets `$_SESSION['mobile'] = 'off'`.

The main Site executes the following code:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  // Did the User come back from mobile.php?
  if ($_SESSION['mobile'] != 'off') {
    include 'Mobile_Detect/Mobile_Detect.php';
    $detect = new Mobile_Detect();
    // Smartphone?
    if ($detect->isMobile() && !$detect->isTablet()) {
      // Redirection --> echo 'JS'
      echo "<script>window.location='mobile.php'</script>";
    }
  }
?>
```

The Problem seems to be that `if ($_SESSION['mobile'] != 'off')` is ignored or wrong. My iPhone always sends me straight back to 'mobile.php'.

Can anyone help?

Perhaps I should show you the code from 'mobile_off.php':

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['mobile'] = 'off';
?>
```

Comment: try using !== instead of !=

Comment: echo $_SESSION['mobile'] and see what it prints

Comment: !== shows the same behavior. $_SESSION['mobile'] shows nothing.

Comment: you know, a responsive layout could solve this. (give it a few minutes, i know someone here will shoot me)

Comment: Haha. This would have been my solution but I am not allowed to change the whole page.

Comment: Okay, I tracked it down to a missing path for `session.save_path` and now `Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by...` Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to first check the session variable exists or not  before checking the value of session variable.
For checking if session variable is set or not try this code

```
if(isset($_SESSION['mobile'])
```

After that check the value of session variable